# Being asked to write a letter about why I'm fit for a promotion, expected?

Tags: promotion

I've been in my current position for the past year, and have excelled in my position. So recently my manager has brought up the topic of a promotion.

I've been asked to write a letter detailing the things I have done, what more I will do if I were to be promoted. To me this sounds like my manager wants to here in my words why I deserve to be promoted.

I've never been in this position before, so I have no experience to determine if this is expected or not. Have you experience similar requests? Is this a strange ask from my manager?

Answer (score 6):

Self-evaluation is a very common thing, even if it's just part of an annual review process and not tied to a promotion.  It's not strange at all.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common practice. Your manager is nominating your for a promotion and he has to present you to a promotion committee. The committee will decide whether the work you have done meets the requirements for promotion. Hence the letter. Describe your work and the value produced.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you write the letter, and then you give it to a friend or relative who is good at these things to review it and change it if necessary. You need to represent yourself in the best possible light. Some people are good at that, some are not, so if you are not you ask for help.

You want a letter that tells them "Jason is so great, he should have been promoted a lot earlier", not one that says "We wanted to promote Jason, but now I'm not so sure anymore".

Comment: And remember to focus it on how you have shown that you fit the needs of the duties of teh higher position not just that you do your current one well.  For instance if the higher position is mangement , you need to stress your handling of clients or the way you have organized and followed through on projects, your team building skills, etc.